# Let page load, then get the html contents

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-scraping

So, first I have this code

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.roblox.com/groups/'.$groupid);
$elem = $html->find('div[id=ctl00_cphRoblox_GroupClosed]', 0);
```

And then when doing this, I got this

```
<div id="ctl00_cphRoblox_GroupClosed">                                            
    <p>Group Closed</p>
</div>
```

Where I would just filter everything out until I get to `Group Closed`.

---

Now, after the ROBLOX update, they made it that the page will get generated by javascript. So, when I try using the `file_get_html` function, it won't give me alot back. Next to that they changed

```
<div id="ctl00_cphRoblox_GroupClosed"></div>
```

to

```
<span ng-if="showJoinGroupButtonUI() == groupConstants.joinStatus.groupClosed" class="small group-membership-text ng-binding ng-scope" ng-bind="layout.closedGroupText">Group Closed</span>
```

I dont really know how to let the page load, and the scrape the html of the site. As you can see right [here](https://www.roblox.com/groups/3366805). It takes a lot of time to load.

---

Somebody setted my question as a duplicate of a question of 7 years ago. I am using a shared webhosting with directadmin. So installing PhantomJS, won't really work out for me..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you could do this using php anymore, since pphp will return the source code of the page as it returns from the server.

You might want to look at other solutions like puppeteer,phantomjs etc.
Those are headless js engines which can actually wait for functions to load, and get the source code and DOM elements as if you're inside a browser.